# Include Isotope Items in Wordpress Single posts, no relyout

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I've ran into a problem the other day, trying to implement Isotope to a Wordpress post with clickable resizable images.

I used this demo "http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/zhbLL/3/embedded/result,js,css,html,resources/" and rebuild it, it works fine in a regular HTML file with all the files required and css, but It won't work once I try to apply it to a wordpress post.

The resizing of the imgages just like in the Demo works fine, with the only difference that the images appear twice, when clicked. The other problem is that Isotope items won't relayout when I change the Device / Window size.

Also, the the value of "width:100%" in the CSS for the Div ID Container makes the all Isotope Items dissappear.

I assume this could have something to with the fact that the Isotope items and their Container, are now nested within other containers of the Single.php file.

I'm not sure what's causing this but because I didn't change the CSS in the fiddle I've linked, to test what could cause these problems, I will paste the CSS of the wordpress single.php.

I also made sure both .js files from the fiddle link are working. Isotope is loaded as well as the custom .js script.

CSS for Single post

```
.post-content-content {
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 40px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#content-container {
height: auto;
min-height: 300px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#content {
float: left;
height: auto;
min-height: 200px;
padding-left: 17px;
padding-right: 17px;
top:45px;
left:0;
right:0;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: we cant see if it's only the css

Comment: I removed the #content div which helped to at least get rid off the duplicated images. Still, the Isotope items doesn't respond when changing browser size, only if I click on them

Comment: Its a version problem. <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress4/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script> this line causes a problem. When I remove 1.7.2 it works perfectley I dont now why though.